# Global variable dll export/import

Tags: c++, dll

I got usual macros as below:

```
#ifdef PLATFORM_WINDOWS
    #ifdef BUILD_SHARED
        #define API __declspec(dllexport)
    #else
        #define API __declspec(dllimport)
    #endif
#else
    #define API
#endif
```

(The lib compiles with `/DBUILD_SHARED`)

Then I have a global union object which I want to export/import:
header file:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus  
extern "C" {  
#endif  
//definition of union type   
API extern union U global;  
#ifdef __cplusplus  
} 
#endif
```

source file:

```
// include header
API union U global;
```

The lib compiles fine, but while linking an executable to it I get linker error `unresolved external symbol _global`. I'm using MSVC (VS 2015). Not sure if C linkage has anything to do with it. I'm not even sure if it actually uses C linkage because Intellisense shows as `__cplusplus` is not defined in header file quoted above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Take care about the name mangling.

Comment: @user0042 I know what linker errors are, but I have no idea where this one came from. How do I care about name mangling?

Comment: _"How do I care about name mangling?"_ Compile C code with the C-compiler and C++ code with `extern` with the C++-compiler.